# How to interpret item.fit() result in R?

Tags: r

```
item.fit(e.2pl)

 Item-Fit Statistics and P-values

 Call:
ltm(formula = df.num[, c("q01", "q02", "q03", "q04", "q05", "q06", 
"q07", "q08", "q09", "q10", "q11", "q12", "q13", "q14", "q15")] ~ 
z1)

Alternative: Items do not fit the model
Ability Categories: 10

    X^2 Pr(>X^2)
q01 14.3308   0.0735
q02 27.3738   0.0006
q03 15.8928   0.0439
q04 20.1770   0.0097
q05 21.5241   0.0059
q06 62.6835  <0.0001
q07 26.3082   0.0009
q08 24.8814   0.0016
q09 27.8286   0.0005
q10 44.8325  <0.0001
q11 15.8890    0.044
q12 23.6904   0.0026
q13 32.0169   0.0001
q14 32.7107   0.0001
q15 23.3937   0.0029
```

I am using `item.fit` in `ltm` package.
1. How to decide which item is not fit model?Pr>0.05?
2. How to decide set `G`(ability categories) value in item.fit(model,G)?
3. Should I delete item if item is not fit model?